Creating polygon layer (road border) from line layer (road) and polygon layer (buildings) using QGIS
Picture 1 showing a line layer representing road and a polygon layer representing buildings.
How can I create another polygon layer for the road with the edge touching the buildings e.g. thick orange line in picture 2?


This is the new layer produced.
How do I get the minimum width of each road line buffered (e.g. blue line)?


You can try using Vector > Geoprocessing > Buffer. This will give you a polygon layer of your roads. You can adjust the thickness, BUT it will not care about going over your buildings layer.
To mitigate that, you can use Vector > Geoprocessing > Difference. This will cut the buildings overlapping from your new road polygon layer.
For the minimum width, you can use the ruler in the toolbar

If you want to be able to snap it to edges, you will need to create a temporary line layer. From it, create a line and in the Statistical summary, choose the layer and type "$length", giving you the length of the line.


how to determine the minimum width of the road from the new layer?

For the minimum width, is there automatic approach as I have too many buffered lines to do by the manual creation of the width lines? Thanks!

I have no idea about that. Best option is to open an other question so it is not burried after the first.

Thanks, MesanGeo
